# A multiple choice question about passive voice

Tags: word-choice

This is the question:

> Medicinal chemists know their latest compound _____ seriously as a drug lead until it _____ its punch in animal models.
>
> > A) wasn't taken / proves
> >     B) won't be taken / has proven
> >     C) weren’t taken / would be proven
> >     D) won't take / proves
> >     E) weren't taken / had proved

The answer is "B" but the second part of the answer doesn't make sense. I think it should be "proves" instead of "has proven". Is that right?

Comment: That's is the trouble with these dumbed-down multiple choice language questions. There's nothing *wrong* with ***won't be taken + proves***, which would at least get round any problem deciding between [***has proved***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22until+it+has+proved%22) and [***has proven***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22until+it+has+proven%22) (both of which are acceptable to me, and have many hits in Google Books as per those links).

Comment: ...even more irritating, a check against the Google NGrams AmE corpus shows that *has **proved** its worth* is now more common than *has **proven** its worth* (which sounds more than a little "quaint" to me as a Brit today). These test setters really should try to keep up!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the tenses are not correct together if the answer is "B".

Comment: @S.H.W  No, "has proven" is fine, although I also think "proves" is better.  Have you ever seen the structure, *"once [something] **has [something]ed**"*?  It's not uncommon.

Comment: @Andrew Can you provide other examples from reliable sources for this usage of present perfect tense?

Comment: @Andrew. Absolutely. Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=until+it+finishes%2Cuntil+it+has+finished&year_start=1950&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuntil%20it%20finishes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntil%20it%20has%20finished%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cuntil%20it%20finishes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntil%20it%20has%20finished%3B%2Cc0), ***until it finishes*** overtook ***until it has finished*** some decades ago. But ***until it ends*** has always been far more common than ***until it has ended***. These tests are hopelessly out of touch with the real world.

Comment: @S.H.W: Don't fall into the trap that's already done for your stupid test setter. Neither Simple Present nor Present Perfect are "not correct". They're just *different ways of saying the same thing*, and it's really a waste of time even trying to claim that one is "better" than the other.. But at any given time, one might be more ***popular***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's right provided that they are different ways of saying the same thing. I didn't know that it can be interpreted in that way.

Comment: The thing with this question, is that both bits have to fit. So although '*proves*' may be just as good a fit (or better) as '*has proven*', '*won't take*' [D] does not fit the first gap. '*Wasn't taken / proves*' [A] doesn't work as a combination as it mixes tenses in the wrong way.